# Low SSD Performance Adata SU650

Tags: ssd, benchmarking

I recently got a new computer and am slightly concerned by the benchmark scores I am getting with a CrystalDiskMark and AS SSD. I have an Adata SU650 240 GB SSD.

Here are the scores I get in AS SSD:

- Seq 510 MB/s 175.11 MB/s
- 4K 12.86 MB/s 66.32 MB/s
- 4K-64Thrd 140.20 MB/s 254.08 MB/s
- Acc.time 0.080 ms 0.156ms

Here are the scores I get in Crystal:

- Seq Q32T1 546.7 188.8
- 4 KiB Q8T8 110.9 270.5
- 4 KiB Q32T1 110.4 191.3
- 3 KiB Q1T1 15.22 77.15

I have reinstalled Windows 10 and still get the same sort of scores. Can someone tell me if this is normal for this drive or is there something else that could be causing these poor speeds?

It's the 4K speeds that are concerning me more than anything. 
Should they not be a lot higher? 
Looking at other peoples' results on the Internet,
they are much faster for a similar type of drive.

System Specs

- Intel I7-8700k
- 16 GB DDR4 2666
- Gigabyte B360M-D3P Motherboard
- Adata SU650 SSD
- Seagate Barracuda 2 TB HD

Comment: How is that "low performance"? How those results differ from the manufacturer's specifications?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I think OP is referring to the write speeds. According to ADATA's official [spec sheet](http://www.adata.com/upload/downloadfile/Datasheet%20-%20Ultimate%20SU650_EN_20180910.pdf), write speeds in CDM and AS should be "up to 450" and "up to 430", respectively. However, OP's own tests show 188 and 175 respectively. OP's read speeds seem much more in line with the stated specs.

Comment: It's the 4k speeds that are concerning me more than anything. Should they not be a lot higher, as looking at other peoples results on the internet, they are much faster for a similar type of drive?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you're getting what you're paying for. I'm not claiming it's a bad drive but it's very cheap QLC, reinstall won't help. Basically what you're experiencing is that the drive is using SLC cache when it's quite empty, and that's "up to 430" actually it seems even more. Now it is probably not empty, so you can count on sustained mixed r/w throughput at levels of 30-70 MB/s.

I'm doing some tests of this drive and was looking for materials. Peak throughput is great and totally matches manufacturer's data. So in short i'm not sure about failure rates but that's great driver for desktop OS. Not so great for copying a lot of large files ;)

[Sustained throughput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPmSQ.png)

Comment: We prefer that you not post images that consist primarily of text.  That goes double when the text is not in English.  If you believe that the report you posted supports your answer, please translate the words into English and type them in.